# Adding shortcode to custom post with parameters in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I added this custom post named "candidates" and I wanted to generate a shortcode [candidate] with parameters to make it [candidates id="123"]. Here is my code so far. I wanted to display the thumbnail picture, title, and a button that says "see comments" that redirects to the single post.

```
// >> Create Shortcode to Display Movies Post Types
```

function diwp_create_shortcode_candidates_post_type(){

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'candidates',
                'posts_per_page' => '1',
                'publish_status' => 'published',
             );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()) :

    while($query->have_posts()) :

        $query->the_post() ;
                 
    $result .= '<div class="candidates-item">';
    $result .= '<div class="candidates-poster">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
    $result .= '<div class="candidates-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
    $result .= '</div>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;    

return $result;
```

}

add_shortcode( 'candidates', 'diwp_create_shortcode_candidates_post_type' );

// shortcode code ends here

Comment: Your question does not include any question... ? Do you get any errors, what did you try so far? Thank you.

Comment: Your function is returning, not echoing, so I'm not sure anything would print... also you need to use the shortcode functions to get and extract the parameters. This article might help you: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function recent_posts_function($atts){
  extract(
    shortcode_atts(
      array(
        'post_id' => '',
        // 'extra_param' => '', // you can add more parameters [candidates extra_param=""]
    ),
  $atts)
);

$args = array(
  //'p' => $post_id,                    // will accept single post id only
  'post__in' => explode(" ",$post_id),  // will accept multiple post_id separated by comma
  'post_type' => 'candidates',
  // 'posts_per_page' => $extra_param,  // extra_param added at shortcode_atts at top
  // get the Query Parameters here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
);

$return_string = '';

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($query->have_posts()) :
  $return_string .= '<ul>';
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      // $return_string .= ''; content na to
    endwhile;
  $return_string .= '</ul>';
  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode('candidates', 'recent_posts_function');
```